# How to have the title of the last post in a static page?

Tags: wordpress, post, title

I have a page for posts and a different static home page, as well as other common pages, eg About, Sponsors.

I am trying to have in the header of all pages the name of the site and after the title of the last post. I have tried different functions (the_title(), get_the_title()). It works well in the post page, but for all the remaining I get the title of the page ("About" or "Home" or "Sponsors").

I get that the functions I used so far might only work inside the loop, but was wondering if there's some global way to have the title of the last post available everywhere.

I got to: $posts_page = get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) to get the id of the post page and was trying to find a way from there to get the title of the last post, but no success so far.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
echo current( wp_get_recent_posts( array('numberposts' => 1, 'post_status' => 'publish') ) )['post_title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the latest/most recent post?

Would this work for you?

```
<?php
   $args = array(
       'posts_per_page'   => 1,
       'orderby'          => 'date',
       'order'            => 'DESC'
   );
   $post = get_posts( $args ); 
   $latest_post_title = $post[0]->post_title;
   echo $latest_post_title;
?>
```

Or maybe this is a bit more light weight, not sure but they both do pretty much the same thing.

```
<?php
   $args = array(
      'numberposts' => 1,
   );

   $recent = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
   $last_post_title = $recent[0]['post_title'];
   echo $last_post_title;
?>
```